Dataset Approval/Rejection in Ckan
I'm running a CKAN 2.10.3 on my ubuntu 22.04 server.
I need to configure my application such that the datasets created by an editor of an organization should be in "pending"/"waiting for approval" state.
The admins should be able to review the dataset and accept/reject it accordingly.
Is there any plugins or suggested methods to achieve the same in CKAN 2.10.3
I tried various plugins available such as ckanext-approvalworkflow, ckanext-datasetapproval etc
But these are not yet compatible with CKAN 2.10.3

You don't have many solutions here:

If the listed extensions match your needs, you can raise an issue for these repositories in GitHub and ask about updating the codebase to support the CKAN 2.10.3
There's another extension that should work with CKAN 2.10+ and suggest a similar functionality - https://github.com/dpc-sdp/ckanext-workflow/. It might be not what you need but it still can be helpful for the point #3.
You can write your extension that will implement the mentioned workflow or fork from the extensions you mentioned and update them yourself to match your needs. The AGPL license allows you to customise fork and customise code for your needs.

General suggestions for the #3:

Read the Extending guide in CKAN docs to understand how to create your own extensions - https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.11/extensions/index.html
Read the code from the extensions that are already here to understand the common approach.
Figure out what you need and what you don't need. Formalise all the requirements.
Do it.

